# What to do with "branched" folders in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, high-availability

We've been running a embedded neo4j instance and using the high availability features to ensure a downtimeless roll-over deploy.

We're obviously doing something wrong because we get a 'branched/' folder inside our neo4j database folder. I guess this means that we have branching data (i.e. master switchover doesn't work correctly).

My question is: "what can I do with it?

- can it be safely moved over to a developers workstation while the database is running?
- can we delete it from the server (while the database is running)?
- Is there an api or tool to see the changes inside the branched folder?

Comment: So far, it seems that the folders can safely be removed (we did it while the database wasn't running though)